# How exactly do you say "a wireless computer mouse" in French?

Tags: prépositions, ordre-des-mots, noms

Is **une souris d'ordinateur sans fil** how you would say it? **les souris d'ordinateur sans fil** would be the plural form?

I know that many of you would probably say that **une souris sans fil** is already good enough because just like in English no one would ever stick the word *computer* in there simply because most of the time when we talk about things, we do that under a certain context and therefore certain words just sound redundant if not left out. But the reason I'm asking this is because I want to make sure I've got the order of adjectives correct there. Does the way I have it written there sound fine to you, you think? Could I at least technically switch **d'ordinateur** and **sans fil** around? Would that be totally wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that it would be ambiguous. You can't know which one is wireless: The computer or the mouse ?
In France, if you say « Une souris sans fil », it is clear you are talking about a computer mouse.

**EDIT:**
About grammar, your sentence is correct. You can both say

> les souris d'ordinateur sans fil
>   les souris sans fil d'ordinateur

The first one sounds more natural, even if as said before, it may be ambiguous.

Comment: I agree with my zergish mate. It's obvious that you are talking about a computer mouse. A "wireless computer" today is also ambiguous, is it a laptop ? a tablet ? 
I'd keep "Souris sans fil" too, you clearly are talking about a bluetooth mouse or equivalent.

Comment: @Limo Makes me think, there's the same ambiguity in French and English about whether the mouse is true Bluetooth or "wireless USB" xD And I realized I would say "Une souris d'ordinateur sans fil Bluetooth" but "Une souris d'ordinateur USB sans fil" because "sans fil USB" adds another level of ambiguity xD

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean. We should say what technology the mouse is using, "Radio mouse, bluetooth mouse, Hertz mouse"... :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use

> Une souris sans fil pour ordinateur

but it's quite heavy. 
In this case "*sans fil*" can apply to both the mouse or the computer so you have to clear it up by locating the "*sans fil*" after the mouse.

On the other hand, people will understand because the usual expression is not

> ordinateur sans fil

but

> ordinateur portable

ou juste

> portable